# Update Progressbar according to ImageSwitcher progress

Tags: android, android-progressbar, imageswitcher

I currently have implemented an `ImageSwitcher` in my app, which slides through an array of pictures. Now I want to have a `ProgressBar` under the picture which shows on which position we are in the collection so the user gets a feeling of how much pictures are left.

Is this possible? Can I have some advices on how I might implement this?

Picture:

progress
[--|--------]

My `ImageSwticher`:

```
package com.example.cfaslides;

import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.view.Window;
import android.content.Context;


public class l2_AltInvestActivity extends Activity implements ViewFactory {


ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;

Integer[] imageList = {
R.drawable.av_01,
R.drawable.av_02,
R.drawable.av_03,
R.drawable.av_04,
R.drawable.av_05
};

int curIndex=0;
int maxIndex = 4; //# imageList -1
int downX, upX;

private Animation mIn1, mOut1, mIn2, mOut2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slider);
    final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressB);

mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    mProgressBar.setMax(maxIndex);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

     mIn1 =   AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
     mOut1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
     mIn2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,R.anim.slide_in_right);
     mOut2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,R.anim.slide_out_left);

     AnimationListener mAnimListener = new AnimationListener() {
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // the in animation has ended so update the ProgressBar with the new 
                // progress
                mProgressBar.setProgress(curIndex); // I don't know your progress?!? 
            }   
         @Override
          public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }

          @Override
          public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }
             // rest of the callbacks
     };  
     //set this listener for the both of the in animations 
     mIn1.setAnimationListener(mAnimListener);  
     mIn2.setAnimationListener(mAnimListener);
     // rest of the onCreate method


    imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
    imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in));
    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out));
    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageList[curIndex]);
    imageSwitcher.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                downX = (int) event.getX();
                Log.i("event.getX()", " downX " + downX);
                return true;
            }
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                upX = (int) event.getX();
                Log.i("event.getX()", " upX " + downX); 

                if (upX - downX > 100) {
                    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
                    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right));
                    //curIndex  current image index in array viewed by user
                    curIndex--;
                    if (curIndex < 0) {
                        curIndex = maxIndex; //maximum
                    }

                    //imageList :-image list array
                    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageList[curIndex]);
                    //GalleryActivity.this.setTitle(curIndex);
                }
                else if (downX -upX > -100) {
                    curIndex++;
                    if (curIndex > maxIndex) {
                        curIndex = 0;
                    }
                    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,R.anim.slide_in_right));
                    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,R.anim.slide_out_left));
                    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageList[curIndex]);
                    //GalleryActivity.this.setTitle(curIndex);
                }
            return true;
            }
        return false;
        }
    });
} //END onCreate

@Override
public View makeView() {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
    return i;   
} //END makeView

} // END Class
```

Slider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget32"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressB"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>

</ImageSwitcher>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now i like to have an progress bar under the picture which shows on
>   which position we are in the collection. so that someone gets a
>   feeling how much pictures are left.

1. Place a `ProgressBar` in your `R.layout.slider` layout file
2. Make the four different `Animations` that you used for the `ImageSwitcher`'s transitions as fields in your `Activity` and also set an `AnimationListener` for each of them:

   ```
   //...
   private Animation mIn1, mOut1, mIn2, mOut2;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.slider);
       final ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheProgressBar);
       mIn1 =   AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
       mOut1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
       mIn2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,R.anim.slide_in_right);
       mOut2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(l2_AltInvestActivity.this,R.anim.slide_out_left);
       AnimationListener mAnimListener = new AnimationListener() {

       public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
           // the in animation has ended so update the ProgressBar with the new 
           // progress
           mProgressBar.setProgress(curIndex); // I don't know your progress?!? 
       }   
        // rest of the callbacks
       });  
       //set this listener for the both of the in animations 
       mIn1.setAnimationListener(mAnimListener);  
       mIn2.setAnimationListener(mAnimListener);
       // rest of the onCreate method
   ```
3. In the `onTouch` method update the `ImageSwitcher` with the proper animations(from `mIn1`, `mOut1`, `mIn2`, `mOut2`)

Comment: hey, thanks for that, but now the app crashes if i will open the slider menu: it says 01-13 12:16:27.335: E/AndroidRuntime(3495): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cfaslides/com.example.cfaslides.l2_AltInvestActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't add more than 2 views to a ViewSwitcher            ... i have Updates the code at the top

Comment: @user1966046 Don't place the `ProgressBar` **inside** the `ImageSwitcher` tags(meaning inside of  the <ImageSwitcher></ImageSwitcher> tags), you have to place it outside of those tags.

Comment: well thanks this is working now, but it didn't update the progress in the bar. i initialised it with 0 and set maximum to max:mProgressBar.setProgress(0); mProgressBar.setMax(maxIndex); mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); i think the bar issn correctly connected tot the ontouch listner ?

Comment: @user1966046 I used `curIndex` as the new value of the progress(see my code in the answer), if you just use `setProgress(0)` it's normal that you don't modify the progress as you set the progress to the same value, `0`.

Comment: hmm i thought that the method sets the right count  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        mProgressBar.setProgress(curIndex); 
    }

Comment: ... the setProgress(0) i set in the onCreate Method  final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressB);

mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    mProgressBar.setMax(maxIndex);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: @user1966046 Ok, but you also followed point 3 of my answer to actually use the `mIn1`, `mOut1`, `mIn2` and `mOut2` in the `onTouch` method **instead** of the `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(/**/)` ?

Comment: ok well i missed this... now the bar is doing something but it is getting invisble after the animation... is it possible to see the bar all the time ?

Comment: @user1966046 I don't see how would the `ProgressBar` become invisible. Your layout should be like this https://gist.github.com/4524101 . See if this makes a difference.